# What would be the consequence for the Earth if the moon's orientation was flipped?

Tags: space

I'm trying to write up a story in which superpowers exist, and I created a hero in which he could flip *anything*. People, the Earth, the Moon. I wanted to make him try to destroy the world, so what would happen if the Moon's orientation was completely flipped?

Comment: Flipped as in north becomes south, or something else? Do you even know or care whether let's say Mare Serenitatis is in the northern or the southern lunar hemishere?

Comment: The moon is a sphere. What are you expecting that flipping it, around any axis, do? Are you flipping its axis of orbit?

Comment: Sorry, should've been more clear. I was thinking, if the Moltke crater was facing the Earth, the hero would be able to completely turn it around to face the opposite way. I was trying to think along the lines of how the oceans would react, seeing as the moon manipulates the tides.

Comment: He just needs to use his powers to flip (reverse) the polarity.

Comment: How fast and often can he flip something? I would imagine that "flipping" the earth, as in "switch night and day", every few seconds would be a problem for most animals and plants. This way the earth would not be destroyed, but everyone one earth would feel threatened by your "hero".
BTW: Why is your "hero" trying to destroy the earth? Sounds more like a villain to me.

Answer (score 3):

### Practically nothing

The moon is roughly spherical, meaning that its gravity is relatively constant no matter how it's turned. Sure, its albedo (reflectivity) may change if we're exposed to previously volcanic areas that we hadn't seen before - but on the whole, no major consequences should arise.

### Your character can still do harm, however.

[image]
All they need to do is flip **part** of an existing object - instead of the whole thing! This could be devastating if used on the Earth, moon, sun, etc - all would have irreversible, immediate effects.